# Add timeout to Bash script to check hosts with curl?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, shell-script, bash-scripting

I made a bash script to go through every host in a txt file and return if the HTTP response is 200 ok or not. But it is very slow, and I want to make it faster with a timeout, waiting for the host.

I think I can make it wait a few seconds – and if the host dosen't respond, it should go to the next host in the list.

How can I do this with bash scripting, or – if it is a bad idea – can you give me an alternative solution for this?

I'm totally new to Bash.

```
for host in $(cat 'hackit.txt');
do
    echo $host
    curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{http_code}\n' $host
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from `man curl`:

> -m, --max-time
>
> Maximum  time  in seconds that you allow the whole operation to take.
>                 This is useful for preventing your batch jobs from hanging for  hours
>                 due  to slow networks or links going down.  Since 7.32.0, this option
>                 accepts decimal values, but the actual timeout will decrease in accu‐
>                 racy  as  the  specified timeout increases in decimal precision.

and:

> --connect-timeout
>
> Maximum time in seconds that you allow  curl's  connection  to  take.
>                 This only limits the connection phase, so if curl connects within the
>                 given period it will continue - if not it will exit.   Since  version
>                 7.32.0, this option accepts decimal values.

This said, you can also combine this with @slhck `parallel` suggestion to run queries in parallel.

Comment: Good idea. I'm so used to doing most things in parallel that I forget that some tools have such options included.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [GNU `parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) for that. It has a timeout option that terminates individual jobs, and you can also process the URLs in parallel, which massively speeds up the job.

For example if you have a list:

```
$ cat urls.txt
http://example.com
http://example.com/foo
http://example.com/?blah
http://some-non-existing-host.com/
```

Run the `curl` command with `parallel`:

```
$ parallel --timeout 5 "curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{url_effective} %{http_code}\n' {}" < urls.txt 2> /dev/null
http://some-non-existing-host.com/ 000
http://example.com 200
http://example.com/?blah 200
http://example.com/foo 404
```

Note:

- `--timeout 5` kills each individual job after 5 seconds.
- I've modified the `--write-out` option so that it prints the URL and the status code in one line separated by a space. This way you can better parse the result.
- You can redirect the result to a file with `> results.txt`.
- The `2> /dev/null` is needed to suppress warnings about timed out jobs.
- The jobs are not executed in the order given in the original list, but that should not really matter.

Comment: Use `-P 0` to run many in parallel. With `--tag` you can keep the original `--write-out`.